# Huawei Y6 (2019) stuck in boot-loop after stand-by, how can I recover my data from the device?

Tags: data-recovery, boot-loop, huawei

My, completely unmodified, Huawei Y6 (2019) is stuck in a Boot-Loop since I wanted to leave the Stand-By a few days ago. Generally it's unresponsive, cannot be put into recovery mode either. Only when I plug it into a power source does it turn on for a short moment, displaying the Huawei-Label before turning black immediately and repeating that loop until I unplug it. While I am aware that there are options like flashing the phone or doing a hard reset, I would like to know if it's possible to save some of my data from this phone. Several notes, photos, videos and contacts are stuck there. That's pretty much the only relevant stuff on it, so if it's possible to get that data off this phone, even if it might brick the device, it would be appreciated to hear some thoughts and answers in that direction.

Comment: Unfortunately the only way to recover data is fix the issue and boot into android, then unlock screen with credentials. TL;DR data is lost